# How can I achieve a popup like this from within a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uibutton, uitextview

I have an app for iPhone / iPod touch that has an UITextView and I would like to add button(s) inside the UITextView. The UITextView contains names one after the other like this:

```
firstname <button>
secondname <button> ...
```

I would like to add a `<button>` near each name and when I tap it a view should appear that looks like this:

[image]

In this other application, an overview appears with two buttons when the plus button is clicked.

How can I achieve such a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a UIWebview and doing everything in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link http://three20.info/ . Its three20 library , you can much more here than what you are asking . But it would be too time consuming if this is the only thing you want to implement.

Other way is to create the custom view with two buttons and make it visible on the button tap. Hope this helps.